# React with ES7: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm getting this error ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined*** whenever I type anything in the input box of AuthorForm. I'm using React with ES7.

The error occurs on **3rd line of setAuthorState function in ManageAuthorPage**. Regardless of that line of code even if I put a console.log(this.state.author) in setAuthorState, it will stop at the console.log and call out the error.

Can't find similar issue for someone else over the internet.

Here is the **ManageAuthorPage** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthorForm from './authorForm';

class ManageAuthorPage extends Component {
  state = {
    author: { id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
  };

  setAuthorState(event) {
    let field = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.state.author[field] = value;
    return this.setState({author: this.state.author});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthorForm
        author={this.state.author}
        onChange={this.setAuthorState}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ManageAuthorPage
```

And here is the **AuthorForm** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AuthorForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
                <h1>Manage Author</h1>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                    name="firstName"
          className="form-control"
                    placeholder="First Name"
          ref="firstName"
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
                    value={this.props.author.firstName}
          />
        <br />

        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text"
                    name="lastName"
          className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Last Name"
          ref="lastName"
                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
          value={this.props.author.lastName}
                    />

                <input type="submit" value="Save" className="btn btn-default" />
            </form>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthorForm
```

Comment: You MUST NOT modify state directly. There is `asynchronous` **setState(...)** for this.
I am writing about this statement `this.state.author[field] = value;`.

Comment: simply convert `setAuthorState(event) {...};` to `setAuthorState = (event) => {...};` otherwise you have to bind (this) explicitly

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `super()` as the first thing in your constructor.

You should set `this` for `setAuthorState` method

```
class ManageAuthorPage extends Component {

  state = {
    author: { id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAuthorChange = this.handleAuthorChange.bind(this);
  } 

  handleAuthorChange(event) {
    let {name: fieldName, value} = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [fieldName]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthorForm
        author={this.state.author}
        onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Another alternative based on `arrow function`:

```
class ManageAuthorPage extends Component {

  state = {
    author: { id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
  };

  handleAuthorChange = (event) => {
    const {name: fieldName, value} = event.target;

    this.setState({
      [fieldName]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthorForm
        author={this.state.author}
        onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: alternative method worked for me Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 97):

You have to bind your event handlers to correct context (`this`):

```
onChange={this.setAuthorState.bind(this)}
```

Comment: I used your example mate. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Khpalwalk You are welcome :-)

Comment: I find a more eloquent way of doing this is by using arrow functions which will inherently bind this to the function, I find it especially useful when writing react code. So you can use setAuthorState=event=>{...}. No extra lines of code are necessary to bind this to the function. Also, every time this component is clicked it doesn't require the extra costs of binding this.

Comment: @BrettReinhard you are right, currently that's probably the most convenient way. Anyway, JS programmers need to understand the reason of context binding

Comment: I agree, I feel as though 'this' eludes many developers and they don't fully understand what 'this' truly represents. I feel as though in react developers have a better understanding of 'this', now whether that is purely superficial is another thing. For those that don't understand 'this' should take a look at Kyle Simpsons , you don't know js repo on github. His username is getify, and has a few chapters dedicated to 'this' that will help get the ball rolling in understanding what 'this' means in the given context.

Comment: yes thank u it is working for me. I forgot to to use bind in my code.

Comment: yes thank u it is working for me. I forgot to to use bind in my code.

Comment: do that in your constructor